# What is the best way to display an image without card when using GridViewPager

Tags: wear-os

So I have a `GridViewPager` that currently displays a 3xN grid, N being the number of items in the list. I have an image in the background of all cards, but for the rightmost column, I'd like to show the image without a card in front of it.

I'm using a `FragmentGridPagerAdapter` and `getBackground` for the background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the sample app in the SDK which sets a card fragment for each page in the adapter? If so you can just use your own fragment, it doesn't have to be a card one, in your case it could be a fragment without any views in it.